# Awk command in bash using variable

Tags: bash, awk

how can i search the first column of a file and get the corresponding value from second column using variable as search criteria?

I need something like this...

```
for pdf in $reports
do
id=` less /path/file | awk '$1 == pdf {print $2}'`
do other stuff
done
```

Comment: `less` is not helping you in this case. Decompose your problem to simpler steps. `awk -v var="strVal" '{$1 == var {print $2}' /path/file` is the place to start. Good luck.

Comment: Can you clarify more what the data in the files might look like and what the contents of `$reports` is?

Comment: @shellter, ...I'm presuming the leading `{` was in error

Comment: It is a file with 3 columns so i wanna find a match on the first column (matching whatever is in my variable) and get the corresponding value of the second column for that match.

Comment: @shellter how do i assing the output to a variable? Like id= `awk ....`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks@

Comment: @charlesDuffy , yep, thanks for pointing that out! "Vandré Dreer Bonaite", you were almost there, glad you found your solution! Good luck.